# Как сделать запрос по данной таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть задание: Выведите название продукта, цену, количество проданный штук в каждом заказе, добавьте поле «сумма проданного товара» за исключением товара под маркой Samsung

схема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я сделал: SELECT Name, Price, 
FROM Products

вопрос: как быть с количество проданный штук в каждом заказе, добавьте поле «сумма проданного товара» за исключением товара под маркой Samsung?

Comment: Какие поля и таблицы отвечают за необходимые вам данные?

Comment: полный вопрос: Согласно приведённой ниже схеме данных выполните запрос: Выведите название продукта, цену, количество проданный штук в каждом заказе, добавьте поле «сумма проданного товара» за исключением товара под маркой Samsung (марку выбираете произвольно

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что прямо писать для вас запрос неправильно, тем более если это задание.

Вы пишите, что сделали `SELECT Name, Price, FROM Products`, но в таблице `Products` нет поля `Price`, т.е.  пока вы даже структуру не пронализировали.

Ключевыми словами в вашем задании являются **"в каждом заказе"**, т.е. вы должны отталкиваться от таблицы `OrderDetails`, в ней есть ссылка на таблицу `Products`, чтобы получить название (это, наверное и есть марка) продукта. Перемножить два поля для получения  суммы проданного товара тоже не проблема. Для последнего шага потребуется добавить условие через ключевое слово `where` и проанализировать схему.